# Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to canvas and Js so just trying to make a basic game.
currently I am simply trying to draw a rect on the canvas that I can move around with arrow keys.
I keep gettign this error and nothing seems to fix it

This is the basic JS code for the game it was once I added the code to draw and move the rect that this error was thrown up

```
//canvas//
const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas1");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log(canvas)

//score bord//
score = document.getElementById("playerscore");
let currentScore = 0;

//game//
function startGame() {
  const myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    score.textContent = "Score: " + currentScore++;
  }, 1000);

  //player movment//

  const player = {
    x: 350,
    y: 250,
    speed: 3,
  };

  let left = false;
  let right = false;
  //   let up = false;
  //   let down = false;

  function move() {
    if (left) {
      player.x -= player.speed;
    }

    if (right) {
      player.x += player.speed;
    }
  }

  //test for key press//
  document.onkeydown = function () {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) left = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) right = true;
  };

  document.onkeyup = function () {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) left = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) right = false;
  };
    function clearcanvas() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

   function block(x,y)
   // let x = 350
   // let y = 250

    ctx.filltyle = "red"
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(x,y)
    ctx.lineTo(x+15,y+50)
    ctx.lineTo(x-15,y-50)
    ctx.fill()

  setInterval(update, 10);

  function update() {
    clearcanvas();
    block();
    move();
  }
}

//play button//
const startgame = document.getElementById("startgame");
startgame.addEventListener("click", function () {
  startGame();
});

//game over//

function endGame() {
  function myStopFuction() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
  finalScore = currentScore;
  console.log(finalScore);
  ctx.font = "50px Courier New";
  ctx.fillStyle = "bold";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText("Game Over", 350, 250);
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + finalScore, 350, 200);
}

const endgame = document.getElementById("endgame");
endgame.addEventListener("click", function () {
  endGame();
});
```

Here is the HTML Site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Block Dodge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Block Dodge</h1>
    <h4 id="playerscore">Score: 0</h4>
    <button id="startgame">Start Game</button>
    <button id="endgame">End Game</button>

    <canvas id="canvas1" width="700" height="500"> </canvas>
  </body>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements, not one. That's why "elements" is plural in the name.